# How to access variable outside the function scope Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm learning angular and i'm trying to access the variable value outside the scope. I have tried using `this`. It didn't work, help me

```
export class DashboardComponent   {
  private population: number;
  private country: string;
  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {
    this.myData();
  }

  myData(){
     this.dummyService.getList().subscribe((data) => {
      this.response = data;
        this.population = this.response.map(data => data.population);
        this.country = this.response.map(data => data.country);
        //able to console it here

    });
    //not able to console it here
  }

     chart1 = {
      data: {
        labels: this.country,// want to access it here
        datasets: [{
          label: 'population',
          data: this.population, // want to access it here
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          borderColor: '#5b6582',
          borderWidth: 2
        },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              fontColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.6)',
              fontStyle: 'bold',
              beginAtZero: true,
              maxTicksLimit: 8,
              padding: 10
            }
          }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          display: false
        },
      }
    };

ngOnInit() {

    new Chart('chart-line', {
      type: 'line',
      data: this.chart1.data,
      options: this.chart1.options
    });
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to console? Variable name I mean from you code?

Comment: @WahabShah I want to access  `this.country` & `this.population` in my `chart1`

Comment: So what is happening is before your this.population and this.country is populated chart1 is executed and data is being used before it is populated. Just try one thing if it works I will tell you the optimal solution then. Put your chart1 inside a function if you want like initChart(), whihch you have already liek Hien said and call it inside a  setTimeout() to delay its call. I am certain you will receive your data in chart1. If this works let me know we will use your service handlers to resolve this then.

Comment: Just inside your myData(), put a setTimeout() with 5-10 seconds delay for testing purposes (and call chart1 inside the timeOut)

Answer (score 0):

You should create variable `chart1` and create `initChart()` and call before your get data method.

```
 export class DashboardComponent   {
      private population: number;
      private country: string;
      chart1 : any;
      constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {

        this.myData();
      }

      myData(){
         this.dummyService.getList().subscribe((data) => {
          this.response = data;
            this.population = this.response.map(data => data.population);
            this.country = this.response.map(data => data.country);
            //able to console it here
            this.initChart();
        });
        //not able to console it here
      }

      initChart(){
        let seft = this;
         chart1 = {
          data: {
            labels: self.country,// want to access it here
            datasets: [{
              label: 'population',
              data: self.population, // want to access it here
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              borderColor: '#5b6582',
              borderWidth: 2
            },
            ]
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  fontColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.6)',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  maxTicksLimit: 8,
                  padding: 10
                }
              }]
            },
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
              display: false
            },
          }
        };
     }

ngOnInit() {

    new Chart('chart-line', {
      type: 'line',
      data: this.chart1.data,
      options: this.chart1.options
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I do have ngOnInit menthod to initialise my chart. I have updated the code

Comment: In `initChart()` method, i'm not able to access `this.country` & `this.population`. throwing an error undefined

Comment: Not working. If i subscribe it inside `initChart()` then it's working. Don't know the reason

Comment: You should move initChart inside subscrible myData function

Comment: If i give hard code values in array then i'm able to see the graph, If i'm trying to access it through this keyword from my subscription, it's not working. Can you initiate a chat, so i can show you the code

Comment: If you observe my code chart1 is type defined. It should be outside the method